# Facebook Web app development: Storing user access token in a session variable

Tags: php, session, facebook-graph

If i store facebook user access token in session variable , as there will be huge users (may be 10000 daily) will it cause the hosting server any issue ?

**EDIT 1:**

Server specification: 400mb disk space, 3GB bandwidth on monthly, as it is a shared hosting ram is not mentioned. The access token is 255 characters long.

Comment: How big is the data?   How long do sessions last?   How much memory do you have available on your hosting plan?   Without knowing a bunch of details, this question is difficult to answer.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please do kindly help me with this